Landscape client not reporting package information to landscape server
Ubuntu OS version installed on hosts: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Landscape standalone master server version - 23.03
Landscape client version installed - 23.08
Python version: Python 3.10.12.
Both machines have Ubuntu Pro license attached
I was able to register client using syntax:
landscape-config --account-name={LANDSCAPE_ACCOUNT_NAME} --computer-title={COMPUTER_TITLE} --registration-key={KEY}

However when I lick on tab "Packages" for this host I get pop display "No package information is available for the selected computers."
All other information is reported correctly expect Distribution on the Info page for the client is "Unknown".
Troubleshooting solutions:

tried removing client from register and re-register, no change in results
made sure all packages installed are up to date on both hosts
On the client :
/var/log/landscape/broker.log: reports no errors, messages are
actively exchanged
/var/log/landscape/package-reporter.log: Generates python3 errors:


        ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
    2024-04-04 13:57:26,700 ERROR    [MainThread] None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/package/taskhandler.py", line 229, in got_server_uuid
        lsb_release_info = parse_lsb_release(self.lsb_release_filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/lsb_release.py", line 32, in parse_lsb_release
        dist, desc, release, code_name, _ = lsb_info.decode().split("\n")
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
    2024-04-04 14:20:24,885 ERROR    [MainThread] None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/client/package/taskhandler.py", line 229, in got_server_uuid
        lsb_release_info = parse_lsb_release(self.lsb_release_filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/lsb_release.py", line 32, in parse_lsb_release
        dist, desc, release, code_name, _ = lsb_info.decode().split("\n")
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)



I was having a similar issue and what seemed to fix this issue for me was uninstalling lsb-release, uninstalling the landscape-client then re-installing the client and let it install lsb-release itself. Uninstalling lsb-release masked the landscape-client service for me so If it does that just unmask it and re-install it. I could see this breaking some other things on your system if they rely on lsb-release, but it didn't for me, so do at your own risk I guess.
sudo apt remove lsb-release
sudo apt remove landscape-client
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt install landscape-client

Then just follow the normal way you'd connect a client to Landscape. I did also restart the system after all of this.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
